# Python: How to transform DF into Json series?

Tags: python, json, reactjs, dataframe, highcharts

I have the following Dataframe in python:

[image: date(index]

And I want to transform it into the the following json object so I can send it to front end and plot it on highcharts:

```
 name: 'netflix',
  data: [
    [1579996800, 67],
    [1580601600, 70],
    [1581206400, 68],
    [1581811200, 72],
    etc...
  ]
}, {
  name: 'netflix movies',
  data: [
    [1579996800, 59],
    [1580601600, 69],
    [1581206400, 71],
    [1581811200, 63],
    etc...
  ]
}]
```

Im using:

```py
    json = df.to_json()
```

But I get something very close but the date it's showing up as an index and not as a value. It's ok that shows timestamp but I want it to be `[1579996800, 67]` and not `[1579996800: 67]`

How do I get an JSON Array of objects: [ {x : x value, y: y value}, {x : x value, y: y value}, ...] from this dataframe? So I can send to the front end and plot using highcharts?

[image]

If I reset the index then everything gets messy. What would be the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using just Python's powerful list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, datetime as dt
now = dt.datetime.now()
r = lambda: np.random.randint(0,100,10)
td = lambda i: now+dt.timedelta(i)
dic = {"date": [td(i) for i in range(10)], "netflix": r(), "Netflix movie": r(),  "Netflix stock": r(),  "Netflix login": r(),  "Netflix party": r(), }
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

req_json = {col: [[a,b] for a, b in zip(df['date'],df[col])] for col in df.columns[1:]}
```

Comment: Thank you. But With this I get a list of dictionaries. I need to send the data to front end as a json object. How can I transform that list into a json object?

Comment: The required output in your question is a list of dictionaries...If you modify it I can modify answer... In your image I don't see "name" and "data" keys..Should I remove it and make `req_json` a dictionary?

Comment: Updated my question. I need to get like Array of objects: [ {x : x value, y: y value}, {x : x value, y: y value}, ...]

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly how I need the data. Question is I'm using flask and sending back the data to React. Can I send ```req_json``` as it is? Will it work?

Comment: @Sundios Yes it should

Comment: Dude! You are the best! It works perfectly now. Thank you so much.